# Setting up rfigshare with API keys

Tags: r, api

I have recently installed the **rfigshare** package. In order to use it, I need to get figshare API keys to to use it properly. The documentation I found so far is obsolete (see [here](https://github.com/ropensci/rfigshare/blob/master/inst/examples/getting_started.md)). Does anyone knows the procedure to follow?

Answer (score 1):

From [the package README](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rfigshare/README.html):

> The first time you use an rfigshare function, it will ask you to authenticate online. Just log in and click okay to authenticate rfigshare. R will allow you to cache your login credentials so that you won't be asked to authenticate again (even between R sessions), as long as you are using the same working directory in future.

So, just load the package using `library("rfigshare")` and call any function. You will be automatically prompted to login and store an OAuth credential locally, which will then be automatically used in subsequent function calls.